# how to set icon of same color in android.support.design.widget.NavigationView?

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

This is the code i have written to get the navigation drawer using android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`

```
<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

`
and the menu i used to inflate is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJaWo.png) where the color of the icon is blue in color.

but after inflating to the NavigationView It comes with different color as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbbhQ.png)

Please help me solving it.

Answer (score 1):

First use Updated support lib version "v7:23.1.1"

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="2"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    app:itemIconTint="#FF00E5FF"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
    />
```

itemIconTint set the color for icon ,if you want do not set color then use

app:itemIconTint="#00000000"